# XNA shader works correctly on one machine but not on another

Tags: c#, git, xna

I am working on a game in C#/XNA which uses custom shaders for drawing. When the code is compiled on my machine it works perfectly on all computers I tested, but when my team member tries to compile it locally, there are very weird visual artifacts. The walls of our maze are stretched to what looks to be infinity based on that they seem to end at the far plane of the game camera.

We both use visual studio 2013 with XNA game studio 4 and we can't find any differences in our build settings (which should come from our git repository anyway). We also tried copying our code files directly from one computer to another, but it resulted in the same.

Now we are totally lost in what to do next. Any ideas what it could be?

[image: Working Maze on my computer]
Working Maze on my computer

[image: Broken Maze on their computer]
Broken Maze on their computer

Comment: Two things: you might want to try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ and you should post your shader code.

Comment: Have you checked the graphics drivers / graphics hardware on this team member's computer?

Comment: Good ones, thanks. When it's compiled it works on all computers, so there should be no problem on the hardware side.